# How to implement toObject() method generic while using Firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, generics, google-cloud-firestore

How to make this **getData(String)** method genric so that I can pass any type of POJO class in it. I wanted to pass a generic type class **Model** into toObject() method in

```
case ADDED:
     Model model = dc.getDocument().toObject(Class<Model>);
```

and

```
case MODIFIED:
    Model model1 = dc.getDocument().toObject(Model.class);
```

> `Model.class` shows Cannot select from a type variable and `Class<Model>` just shows an error.

**Here is the code**

```
public List<Model> getData(String path){

    db.collection(path)
            .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots,
                            @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

            if (e != null || queryDocumentSnapshots == null)
                return;

            List<DocumentChange> documentChanges = queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges();

            if(documentChanges.size() != 0 && mAdapter != null) {

                List<Model> newList = new ArrayList<>(oldData);

                for (DocumentChange dc : documentChanges) {
                    switch (dc.getType()) {
                        case ADDED:
                            Model model = dc.getDocument().toObject(Class<Model>);
                            newList.add(model);
                            break;
                        case MODIFIED:
                            Model model1 = dc.getDocument().toObject(Model.class);
                            newList.set(model1);
                            break;
                        case REMOVED:
                            Log.d("debug","REMOVED");
                            break;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Did you find solution for this?

Comment: No @Yupi Not yet